# Xamarin Forms can't change variable value

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to make a simple Stopwatch app with xamarin forms.

Here is the interface :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testvb"
             x:Class="testvb.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding LabelText}">
            <Label.BindingContext>
                <local:GetDuration/>
            </Label.BindingContext>
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Command="{Binding TapCommand}">

                </TapGestureRecognizer>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding SWDuration}">
            <Label.BindingContext>
                <local:GetDuration/>
            </Label.BindingContext>
        </Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding StartTimeText}">
            <Label.BindingContext>
                <local:GetDuration/>
            </Label.BindingContext>
        </Label>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

And the c#-class:

```
namespace testvb
{
    class GetDuration : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        static string labeltext = "START";
        static string starttimetext = "Timer hasn't been started";
        ICommand tapCommand;
        static Stopwatch hstopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        string swduration;
        public GetDuration()
        {
            tapCommand = new Command(OnTapped);

            this.SWDuration = hstopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
            {
                this.SWDuration = hstopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();
               return true;
            });

        }

        public ICommand TapCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return tapCommand;
            }
        }

        void OnTapped (object s)
        {
            if(LabelText == "START")
            {
                LabelText = "STOP";
                StartTimeText = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                hstopwatch.Restart();
            }
            else
            {
                LabelText = "START";
                StartTimeText = "Timer has been stopped";
                hstopwatch.Stop();
                hstopwatch.Reset();
            }
        }

        public string LabelText
        {
            get
            {
                return labeltext;
            }
            set
            {
                if(labeltext != value)
                {
                    labeltext = value;
                    if(PropertyChanged!=null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LabelText"));                        
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        public string SWDuration
        {
            get
            {
                return swduration;
            }
            set
            {
                if(swduration!=value)
                {
                    swduration = value;
                    if(PropertyChanged!=null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SWDuration"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public string StartTimeText
        {
            get
            {
                return starttimetext;
            }
            set
            {
                if (starttimetext != value)
                {
                    starttimetext = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StartTimeText"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As from interface I have a label (toogle between start and stop when it is clicked), a label to show the duration, and a label to show the time when the stopwatch was started.

The output on xamarin android simulator:_

- the label (start/stop) works well
- the duration can also be shown on the display BUT the last label won't change.
- Its value stays at "The timer hasn't been started"

I don't understand why it can't work for the last label since the principal ist the same as the first label (start/stop). I would thank you if someone can point out where I misunderstand it or on which part I did wrong on my code.

Thank you.

Comment: Firstly i would suggest to make all your variables instance level. Also i would suggest to show us the xaml.cs file.

Comment: @NickPolideropoulos I read some articles, by variable instance level, do you mean that I shouldn't use static?

Comment: If the answer works then you should mark it as accepted with the check mark. Doing so will help everyone.

Comment: @dev1998 done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the `BindingContext` with

```
<Label.BindingContext>
    <local:GetDuration/>
</Label.BindingContext>
```

separately on each `Label` you are creating a new instance of `GetDuration` for each label. Hence the instance you are invoking `TapCommand` on will be different to the one that is attached to your labels.

By changeing your XAML to

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:stopwatch"
             x:Class="stopwatch.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:GetDuration></local:GetDuration>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding LabelText}">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Command="{Binding TapCommand}">
                </TapGestureRecognizer>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding SWDuration}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding StartTimeText}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

you are creating a single `GetDuration` as the binding context of your page. Unless explicitly set otherwise, the `BindingContext` will be passed to the children of your page, hence there is no need, to set it for each label (disregarding the fact that it did not work anyway).

**Further remarks**

*Event Invocator*

You are raising the event manually from each of your properties. Creating an event invocator that does this for you will save you some lines and make you adhere to DRY more

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Because of the `CallerMemberName` attribute, the name of the calling property will be passed automagically (it's syntactic sugar after all and the compiler will do the magic for you). The properties will become

```
public string StartTimeText
{
    get
    {
        return starttimetext;
    }
    set
    {
        if (starttimetext != value)
        {
            starttimetext = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

*LabelText for the decision*

```
void OnTapped(object s)
{
    if (LabelText == "START")
    {
        LabelText = "STOP";
        StartTimeText = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        hstopwatch.Restart();
    }
    else
    {
        LabelText = "START";
        StartTimeText = "Timer has been stopped";
        hstopwatch.Stop();
        hstopwatch.Reset();
    }
}
```

It may be a matter of taste, but I would not let the decision whether to start or to stop the time depend on the value of `LabelText`, but rather on an internal `bool` or `enum`. The way you are doing it, you internal and external behavior. It's OOP after all and you should make use of encapsulation.

Comment: Implementing your solution does the job for me. So by declaring a new Binding Context on xaml the variable in the C#-file will be new initialized? Do I understand it right?

For the first remark, thank you, I will implement it since it will save me lines and times. 
For the second remark : It is better too to call a function, where in it the variable value will be set?

Thank you very much to take your time to answer my question.

Comment: Yes, a `<local:MyClass />` will *"always"* create a new instance. (well, not really always, since you can define a static factory method and implement the singleton pattern - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-factorymethod-directive) - but though you can do (technically) it does not mean you should.)

Comment: I thank you so much for taking your time to answer my question.